# Is there a directory of open source hardware projects?

Tags: pcb, open-source

I would like to print a fairly common circuit. But I don't want to design the PCB myself. Where should I look when searching for PCB layouts?

Comment: I think this may fall under community wiki, unless a single answer will probably clearly be correct, I think this will have many people posting different questions.

Comment: Any open source hardware retailer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're interested in arduino, there is http://shieldlist.org. It's a wiki listing of all of the boards that can interface to the arduino board. All should be licensed as open hardware.

Comment: I'm very interested!

Comment: It was started and maintained by Jon Oxer of Freetronics

Answer (score 11):

Several places publish open-source PCB design files:

- Olimex sponsors open-source PCB contest every month; all [documentation (including the PCB layout) is posted on the Massmind](http://massmind.org/techref/piclist/pcbcontest.htm)
- Circuit Cellar magazine hosts design contests a couple times a year; often [PCB layout and other documentation is posted on the Circuit Cellar "contests" page](http://www.circuitcellar.com/contests/).
- The [Open Circuits wiki has a list of open-source hardware projects](http://opencircuits.com/Projects).

Sometimes people post open-source hardware design files on one of the popular open-source software places -- Google code, Sourceforge, Launchpad, Github, [etc.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237/i-want-to-start-an-open-source-project-wheres-the-best-place-to-host-i)

A few places are trying to make it easy to buy open-source PCBs -- the actual, physical things you hold in your hands, not merely some computer file:

- BatchPCB will sell more copies of your PCBs to anyone else that wants one. And give you money. Why wouldn't you want that? [BatchPCB discussion forum at Sparkfun](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewforum.php?f=16). A [database of PCBs other people have designed](http://batchpcb.com/index.php/Products).
- Open Source Hardware Bank ([early discussion](http://antipastohw.blogspot.com/2009/03/introducing-open-source-hardware.html)) has a [library of open-source PCBs](http://www.oshwbank.org/)
- Seeedstudio has discussed a [library of open-source PCBs](http://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2008/09/11/an-idea-about-open-source-pcbs/).
- [Arduino Shield List](http://shieldlist.org/) links to the source of many Arduino shield designs. Some of those sources merely publish the PCB layout files; others, in addition, sell the physical hardware -- typically as a kit.

Comment: http://opencircuits.com is interesting

Answer (score 4):

I found some open source hardware at

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=hardware

but there are many software projects in these results also.

The only way I found of getting hardware only results is searching for PCB files:

http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=file%3A%5C.(grb%7Cpcb%7Cpcbdoc%7Cbrd%7Cgto%7C057%7Cgbl%7Cgto%7Cgbo%7Cgts)%24

Comment: The file searches won't catch everything, because different EDA packageshave different naming conventions. .pcb .pcbdoc .brd , .grb .gto .057 .gbl .gto .gbo .gts .gbs etc... off the top of my head

Comment: @Fake thanks, I edited the answer to include a link that searches for all those extensions

Comment: The list I gave is *not* comprehensive. It still may miss some results.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you find something interesting in the Arduino board at Dangerous Prototypes forum:

[Project development, ideas, and suggestions >> Arduino](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/index.php?board=34.0)

Comment: I would like to add: that's a link to the Project development, ideas, and suggestions for Arduino section in the Dangerousprototypes.com forum.

Comment: Added it into the post for you.

Comment: Made it better.

Answer (score 3):

I have built [kitspace.org](https://kitspace.org) with expressly this purpose. It is an open source site for posting open source hardware electronics projects. The site makes it easy for others to find the Gerber design files and buy the required parts.

Answer (score 2):

http://bildr.org/ aims to be a complete open source electronics community (wiki, forum, etc.)

http://www.opencircuits.com/ aims to be a complete open source electronics wiki

(I found both via SparkFun)